# How to reduce ___chunkMapping in Gatsby when rendering MDX?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I create about 200 pages programmatically. According to the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx#updating-createpage-action-in-gatsby-node), I must specify a path to a component for each page in this form `src/templates/Page.tsx?__contentFilePath=...` adding unique __contentFilePath suffix.

This for each page creates a component file (like `component---src-templates-page-tsx-content-file-path-src-content-about-en-mdx-0a71508e3b2d066e3c89.js`) and puts it in the `___chunkMapping` array.

But this leads to a strong increase of `___chunkMapping` in the resulting html files. The content itself is much smaller.

How to act in such a situation? What if there are thousands of pages?